# Adding a button to the bottom of UITableViewController - toolbar alternative

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `UITableViewController` and I want to add a fixed single button to the bottom of the screen.

I don't want it to scroll with the rest of the table. I know that I need the button and the tableview to be at the same level but I have no idea how to do so with a `TableViewController`.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: So far I've tried adding `UIImage` as a subview to `self.view` but it scrolls so, no go. Also thought about `viewForFooterInSection` but read that if the tableview will have sections the button won't be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really explain why a toolbar isn't an option, but that would be the easiest way to do this. You could also do this by making your view controller not inherit from `UITableViewController`, but from `UIViewController`. Then you add a table view that takes up the entire screen, minus a little area at the bottom where you can then put your button.

Comment: I just want a button. I don't want the toolbar blocking the view. If there's an easy way doing so with an alpha toolbar that good be a good solution too.

Comment: So you want the button to float on top of the table view?

Comment: Yes. Float over and stay fixed.

Comment: Then I would go with what I suggested. A `UITableViewController` can be great, but isn't fit for all situations--this being one of them. Create a normal `UIViewController` subclass, with a table view that takes up the entire screen, but also add a button. Not to the table view, but the table view's superview.

Answer (score 1):

in the xib, put the 'UITableview`in a`UIView' (the new 'root' view) and make the `UITableview` in height view.height - about 44px in height, place a UIButton in the view, under the table :)

you will likely need to subclass the tableViewController.. actually no .. you need a default UIViewController instead, which is ok since a tableViewController does not much by itself anyways :D

```
@interface BetterTableVC : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property(weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

Comment: That was my first try but I already have 300 lines of code inside a subclass of `UITableViewController`. When I tried to move that into a subclass of UITableView inside a view I got a lot of errors.

Comment: It shouldn't take much to switch to a subclass of UIViewController. Just change the parent class in the header file, then in `-loadView` make sure you create a table view, add it to your view hierarchy, and set its data source and delegate to self.

Comment: ? ... your subclass just inherits from the stock VC (like the code Ive shown). you dont move any code

Comment: the ONLY change is that self.view != self.tableView